# Asynchronous method not running in proper order

Tags: flutter

I have these methods, for some reason fetchItems is being called first before initPosition, how come dart wont wait for it to finish and proceeds to the second method? I've added async/await but it still doesn't work. I've also checked my backend logs to confirm this. Am I doing something wrong?

```dart
  Future<void> initPosition() async {
    if (_latitude != null && _longitude != null) {
      await Socket.updatePosition(
          lat: 51,
          lon: 17,);
    }
  }
```

```dart
Future<void> initMarkers() async {
   await initPosition();
   await Provider.of<Items>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchItems();
}
```

```dart
  void initMapState() async {

      await getCurrentLocation().then((_) async {
        await initMarkers();
        setState(() {
          _loaded = true;
        });
      });
   
  }
```

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: false);
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      initMapState();
    });
  }
```

```dart
  Future<void> fetchItems() async {
    itemList = await repository.getItemList();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Would please show fetchItems in Provider?

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: I recommend you to use the Future method whenComplete in `initPosition()` like this `await initPosition().whenComplete(() {  here call  fetchItems  })`

Comment: Exactly why do you think that `fetchItems` is called before `initPosition`?  Be specific about what instrumentation you used and what you observed.  There also is a difference between "`fetchItems` is called before `initPosition`" and "`fetchItems` is called before `initPosition` *completes*".  If you mean the latter, possibly `Socket.updatePosition` completes prematurely.  Another possibility is that you're not observing what you think you are (for example, you might be observing multiple calls to `initPosition` and `fetchItems` from different sources).

Comment: @jamesdlin, `fetchItems` should be called whenever initPosition completes. I've tried running code below but still same issue, completely have no idea what is going on. On my backend server still `fetchitems` is being called before `socket`, but it doesn't look like it on dart side

Comment: @squnk You're still giving me vague descriptions.  I don't know what your backend server is logging, whether it's logging when things are initially called or when they complete, etc.  You need to show your exact instrumentation and exact output.  There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you've shown.  Possibly `Socket` (whatever that is; you haven't explained) does not behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Working with multiple asynchronous functions inside Futures depends on whether one is finished or not, not every single one. For this, you can call the "whenComplete" method so you can assure that your future function have finished running. Like this:

For your **initMarkers()** function:

```
  Future<void> initMarkers() async {
    await initPosition().whenComplete((){
      Provider.of<Items>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchItems();
    });
  }
```

For your **initMapState()** function:

```
  void initMapState() async {
    await getCurrentLocation().whenComplete(() async {
      await initMarkers().whenComplete((){
        setState(() {
          _loaded = true;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Keep in mind that, in your code, you are not working with the returning value of your **getCurrentLocation()** function, so instead of using the "then" method use the "whenComplete" method, assuring that you changed or returned your values with this function. Finally, for the **initState()**, make the function body with asynchronous:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: false);
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      initMapState();
    });
  }
```

This should work.

Comment: `.whenComplete` is equivalent to a `finally` block in `try ... catch ... finally`.  It would only make a difference from `.then` if `initMarkers` fails.